# How do I delete trailing slashes when copying and pasting a URL from a web browser to MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My end goal is to take URLS, such as https://google.com/, and format it like so: google.com

Thus far, I have been able to remove "www" and/or "https", but I do not know how to remove the trailing slash when it shows up.

```
Sub quicklink()
With Selection.Range

  .Paste

  If InStr(.Text, "www.") > 0 Then
    .Text = Split(.Text, "www.")(1)



  ElseIf InStr(.Text, "://") > 0 Then
    .Text = Split(.Text, "://")(1)

  End If


  If Right$(.Text, 1) = "/" Then
    .Text = Left$(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1)

  End If


End With
End Sub
```

The second If statement is my (unsuccessful) attempt to delete the trailing slash

Comment: `s = "https://www.google.com/"
    If Right(s, 1) = "/" Then s = Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 1)`

Comment: You can also use the `Replace` command.  That would be a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your Sub to use the `Replace` command.  As you can see, this makes the code cleaner:

```
Sub quicklink()
   With Selection.Range
      .Paste

      .Text = Trim(.Text)
      .Text = Replace(.Text, vbCrLf, "")
      .Text = Replace(.Text, "https://", "")
      .Text = Replace(.Text, "www.", "")
      If Right(.Text, 1) = "/" Then .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1)
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to write `.Text = Replace(.Text, "/", "")` in a way that only removes the last "/" in a link? For example, "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/762937993110713370/" has several slashes, but I only want to remove the last one using the Replace command.

Comment: @JasonReed I modified my code based on your feedback.

Comment: I'm still getting the trailing slash when copying that Pinterest link from the browser to MS Word... any idea why?

Comment: I followed your link, copied and pasted from the address bar, ran the code... and I have no trailing slash.  I did update the code again to make it a little simpler.

Comment: Interesting, I am using a Microsoft Visual Basic window to make the edits while testing them out in a regular Word doc. Could this be why I'm having issues?

Comment: Possible I suppose, but I wouldn't think so.  Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: It highlights `If Right(.Text, 1) = "/"` and then passes through it. The result looks like this: pinterest.com/pin/762937993110713370/ ....I think it's highlighting the space and/or carriage return at the end of the selection. Does our code automatically add those things?

Comment: Looks like there's a trailing space so you need to get rid of it.  See my updated code.

Comment: Turns out, there was a carriage return or newline at the end of the string whenever I copied from the address bar. Thanks for the help!